# What domain does Resolve assume by default?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, logic

Consider the statement: $\forall x\left(x<7\Rightarrow \exists a\exists b\exists
   c(a^2+b^2+c^2=x)\right)$

This is true provided the universe of discourse is $\mathbb{N}$

Now I use `Resolve` as follows to assess the validity of this statement:

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, Implies[x < 7, Exists[{a, b, c}, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == x]]]]
```

and *Mathematica* returns `True`. Why? If I did not specify $\mathbb{N}$ as the domain how does *Mathematica* justify returning `True`? Is there a way to specify $\mathbb{N}$ as the domain?

Answer (score 1):

The *Mathematica* documentation makes it clear that the default domain is `Complexes`. In that domain,

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, Exists[{a, b, c}, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == x]]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

because, in the complex domain, `a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == x` is satisfied by

> ```
> a == Sqrt[x], b == 0, c == 0
> ```

To work with Integers, you can write

```
resolution = 
  Resolve[Exists[{a, b, c}, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == x && 0 < x && x < 7], Integers] // Simplify
```

> ```
> x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 || x == 6
> ```

That all the integers `x` such that `0 < x < 7` are included is easily verified by eye, but to have *Mathematica* automatically verify it, evaluate

```
List @@ resolution[[All, 2]] == Range[6]
```

> ```
> True
> ```